# Complicated relationship with 2 Thorough Models

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have complicated relationship that includes 2 thorough models. I want to create custom method that solves my purpose. I have MySQL DB as datasouce.

3 Main Models.

**Artist, Album, Songs.**

Album and Song are related 2 each other with N:N relationship through model "**Tracklist**". Artist and Tracklist are connected through thorough model "**TracklistArtist**".
I wish to get list of albums and songs of particular artist through this relationship. Though I achieved with patches but it returns duplicate list and same time I want unique record list. Please help.

**I am just mentioning Model relation object here instead of complete model-object.**

artist.json

```
  {
    "name": "Artist",    
    "relations": {
      "tracklists": {
        "type": "hasMany",
        "model": "Tracklist",
        "foreignKey": "",
        "through": "TracklistArtist"
      }
    }     
  }
```

album.json

```
{
"name" : "Album",
"relations": {
    "songs": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Song",
      "foreignKey": "",
      "through": "Tracklist"
    }
  }
}
```

song.json

```
{
"name" : "Song",
  "relations": {
    "albums": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Album",
      "foreignKey": "",
      "through": "Tracklist"
    }
  }
}
```

tracklist.json

```
{
  "name": "Tracklist",
  "relations": {
    "album": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Album",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "song": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Song",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "artists": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Artist",
      "foreignKey": "",
      "through": "TracklistArtist"
    }
  }
}
```

tracklist-artist.json

```
{
  "name": "TracklistArtist",
  "relations": {
    "artist": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Artist",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "tracklist": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Tracklist",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  } 
}
```

**I have checked patched from mysql-connector of loopback.** Here is link. [Check Here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/pull/44)

```
 Artist.tracklists({
                id: $stateParams.artistId,
                filter: {
                   groupBY:"albumId",
                   include: {relation: "album", scope: {}},
                }
            }).$promise.then(function (data) {
            });
```

Comment: Can show your actual code / query ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you need json of my relational models??

Comment: That could help, plus the relevant part of code you use to get  list of albums and songs of particular artist

Comment: I have mentioned model relationship here. As I need to create custom function so I haven't mentioned code What I wrote.

Comment: Great :) Last thing, what module/framework/orm are you using for the database part ?

Comment: I am using Loopback, what they are internal using I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You propably will need to chain your include to get every relations with something like:

```
Artist.find({
  include: {
    relation: 'Tracklist',
    scope: {
      include: {
        relation: ['Album', 'Song']
      }
    }
  },
  where: {id: 12345}
}, function() { ... });
```

Edit:

```
Artist.find({
  include: {
    relation: 'Tracklist',
    scope: {
      include: {
        relation: ['Album']
      },
      scope: {
          include: {
            relation: 'Tracklist',
            scope: {
                include: {
                   relation: ['Song']
                }
            }
        }
    }
  },
  where: {id: 12345}
}, function() { ... });
```

Comment: That I have tried, it gives me duplicate entries of "Albums". Because I have many tracklists. I need unique list of albums and songs.

Comment: From your scheme, a song can be in many albums so it is normal that you get multiple entry of album if a song is reference in many albums, isn't it ?

Comment: Ofcourse relation you mentioned is correct. Artist sings variours songs in album. On same time he has sung same song in different album. Its ok.

This is what the logic I want. I need "Unique Separate list of Albums and Songs". The patch I wrote earlier is same thing you gave example. I tried but I wish to create unique list with custom function.

Comment: Maybe join albums, then includes song for this album... will edit my answer once I have so time..

Comment: @Sankalp: Could you give a try with my second example ?

Comment: I would expect to find either `Album` or `Song` list at a time. Not by any relation. These 2 are separate list and want one at a time. But I want `UNIQUE` list. Am I clear with my point?

Comment: Well, you can also use a raw sql query that will probably be the more efficient...

Comment: Well I have gone thorough patch also. but that didn't work on relational model. I am editing my question with my try. Please check along with this patch.

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/pull/44#issuecomment-136604124